# Transpising observations into one row in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a table if registrations of cars (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qjnl6.png). I need to transpose it into one row per vin number with all info about its registrations so that i will have smth like this:
vin|company_1|start_date_1|end_date_1|company_2|start_date_2|end_date_2|...|company_n|start_date_n|end_date_n, where n is max number of registrations. Please help with code or hints.

I tried proc transpose, but i got start_and and end_date in separate rows, so it doesn't go

```
proc transpose data = test_vin name=VarName out= outdata;

by vin_number;

var company start_date_date9 end_date_date9;

run;
```

Comment: Does not look like a problem that is suited for trying to use TRANSPOSE as the solution.  If you transpose an N by M matrix you get back an M by N matrix, not a vector.  Post the data as actual data instead of photographs.  Post the data you want to get out for the given input.

Answer (score 0):

In the future, please do not post data as images.

You will need to do this manually with a data step. You'll need to first scan your dataset to find the maximum number of columns needed for an array to be sure that there are enough columns for each VIN.

We'll do this with a data step, arrays, and the `retain` statement. We'll continually add values to each array until we reach the last VIN. When we are at the last VIN, we'll output all of our results and reset them.

Sample data:

```
data have;
    input vin$ company$ start_date9:date9. end_date9:date9.;
    format start_date9 end_date9 date9.;
    datalines;
A company1 01JAN2020 05JAN2020
A company2 06JAN2020 10JAN2020
A company3 11JAN2020 15JAN2020
A company4 16JAN2020 19JAN2020
B company5 01FEB2020 02FEB2020
B company6 03FEB2020 10FEB2020
B company7 11FEB2020 20FEB2020
B company8 21FEB2020 28FEB2020
;
run;
```

Code:

```
data want;
    set have;
    by vin;

    array company_[4] $;
    array start_date_[4];
    array end_date_[4];

    /* Do not reset values at the start of each row */
    retain company_: start_date_: end_date_:;

    /* Reset the counter and values for each VIN */
    if(first.vin) then do;
        i = 1;
        call missing(of company_:, of stat_date_:, of end_date_:);
    end;
        else i+1;

    /* Store each company and date */
    company_[i]    = company;
    start_date_[i] = start_date9;
    end_date_[i]   = end_date9;

    /* Only output one row per VIN */
    if(last.VIN) then output;

    format start_date_: end_date_: date9.;
    keep vin company_: start_date_: end_date_:;
run;
```

Output:

```
vin company_1   company_2   company_3   company_4   start_date_1 ...
A   company1    company2    company3    company4    01JAN2020    ...
B   company5    company6    company7    company8    01FEB2020    ...
```